# Is it possible to use a lambda expression in a .cpp file in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, lambda

So [XCode 4.4 claims support for lambdas](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html) and I've used them in some cross-platform code that I'm trying to compile in XCode.  I'm not having any luck, but [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/23922) they mention the requirement of having to use something like dispatch_async or dispatch_once from Grand Central Dispatch.  This indicates that it only works in Objective-C++, not plain C++, which is sort of hinted at in the XCode 4.4 new features list.

Is it possible use them in a conventional C++ sense, such as within `for_each`?

Comment: That linked thread is talking about blocks - are you using blocks?  They're a C/Objective-C feature, not a C++ one.  You'll need to use Objective-C++ if you have block-based code.  I'm not sure how that would work with `for_each`.

Comment: I'm not using blocks, not in my C++ code.

Comment: Then that thread you linked to isn't relevant, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion about `dispatch_*` is someone asking how to use lambdas with GCD. It does not imply that GCD is required or has anything to do with lambdas.

Yes, Xcode supports lambdas in pure C++ code. You simply have to enable C++11 in the project settings. There's a "C++ Language Dialect" setting and you can select between various versions of C++, with or without some additional GNU extensions.

[image]
([image source](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=xcode+c%2B%2B+language+dialect&hl=en&sa=X&tbo=d&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS392US393&biw=1658&bih=1120&tbm=isch&tbnid=w5qrQLPlsLtqhM:&imgrefurl=http://www.futuresvision.net/&docid=R_frBk_I4E0CdM&imgurl=http://www.futuresvision.net/wp-content/uploads/8123a9b1792dfc92a929baf6ce6d3118.png&w=642&h=223&ei=mMrlUIOYCMHUkwWC44CwAg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=640&vpy=774&dur=1562&hovh=132&hovw=381&tx=137&ty=66&sig=109020586284217681329&page=1&tbnh=105&tbnw=297&start=0&ndsp=60&ved=1t:429,r:39,s:0,i:212))

Comment: I did have C++ enabled in the project settings, but the bit I had missed was setting the correct `C++ Language Dialect`.

Comment: how can C++11 be enabled just for one file?

Comment: Select your project in the file navigator, select your target and 'Build Phases' in the editor, expand 'Compile Sources'; There's a 'Compiler Flags' column you can add flags to for individual files. @rraallvv